# Arbitrary or particular

Tags: word-choice

I am writing a procedure to display **an image that the user selects** with the software. When I write my documentation, do I say it's displaying an *arbitrary* image or a *particular* image, or something else?

> - Display Arbitrary Image on the Screen
> - Display Particular Image on the Screen

Comment: `Display image` would be enough, since on the screen is implied by default, and since the user selects the image, he/she would know what image will be displayed. `Arbitrary` means any so it is definitely wrong, `particular` is ambiguous, `selected` should be fine, but redundant.

Anyway, this question is off-topic!

Comment: "Specified" would also work better than either of the given options.

Comment: Thank you guys for advice. Arsen, I guess this question is acceptable since it is not closed by the managing team...

Answer (score 1):

As Arsen Y.M. notes in a comment above, "Display Arbitrary Image on the Screen" has some undesirable connotations as a way of describing a routine that displays an image of the user's choice on the screen. That's because *arbitrary* (according the Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary (2003) can mean (among other things) "existing or coming about seemingly at random or by chance or as a capricious and unreasonable act of will." Although *arbitrary* also has meanings that are much more on point (such as "depending on individual discretion" and "based on or determined by individual preference or convenience rather than by necessity"), the suggestion of a capricious and unreasonable program determining what image the user sees is a must to avoid.

"Display Particular Image on the Screen," on the other hand is so vague as to be almost opaque. Ideally you want the documentation to make clear that the displayed image is one that the user chooses. One way to accomplish this goal is by using the following wording:

> Display User-Selected Image on the Screen

This wording has the advantage of emphasizing that the user is responsible for selecting the image that the software displays. Whether "Display Selected Image on the Screen" would be redundant (as Arsen Y.M. asserts) or not, replacing *Selected* with *User-Selected* surely disposes of that concern.

Another, quite similar option (which Hellion's comment above brings to mind) is this:

> Display User-Specified Image on the Screen

This option, too, leaves no doubt that the user chooses the image and the software makes it appear on the screen. Either option should work fine. I don't have a preference for one over the other.